# is it possible to add multiple datas in one column all at once?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, multiple-columns

I just have a question because I can't seem to find the answer on the internet. I just want to know if is it possible to add multiple data in one column all at once?

Edit: What I meant about multiple data is for instance in my website, I have a Create Set of Officers and I only have one column for the names, an I wanted to insert the names that were created by the admin. Like the name of the President, Vice President, Secretary, etc. I hope you got my point.

Comment: Please define what do you mean with "multiple data".

Comment: edited my question mister @mitkosoft

Comment: Please can you post what you have tried so far, and we may be able to help explain what is what!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to say `INSERT` multiple data in one column and if other columns permits `NULL` then yes you can like

```
insert into your_table(col1,col2,col3)
values (null,null, 1),(null,null, 2),(null,null, 3);
```

Comment: yes, sorry, wrong choice of word. thank you. I'll try it, thank you @Rahul